# Idiomatic way to require all parameters to be set explicitly in a specific invocation? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, constructor, annotations, default, factory

Given two classes with default parameters in their constructor:

```
class Foo(
    val baz: Boolean = false,
)

class Bar(
    val baz: Boolean = false,
)
```

and an extension function to create `Bar`s from `Foo`s:

```
fun Foo.toBar() = Bar(
    baz,
)
```

How would I make sure not to forget to add new properties to `Foo`, whenever they are added to `Bar` (they also have default values)? The following compiles and passes all tests that I would have written at that point.

```
class Foo(
    val baz: Boolean = false,
)

class Bar(
    val baz: Boolean = false,
    val newProp: Boolean = false,
)

fun Foo.toBar() = Bar(
    baz,
)
```

Edit: It is important to note here that this question is really about DTO mapping, so the properties don't always have the same type.

Adding a test only makes sure that properties added to `Foo` and `Bar` are not removed accidentally, because I would need to remember to modify the test, just as I need to remember to modify Foo.

So, how would I make sure to notice I forgot to add something to Foo in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

I would define a common interface between the two classes. When you add features that must be in both classes, add them to the interface, which will prevent those other classes from compiling unless you update their properties/functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have mentioned that the common properties don't always have the same type, since this is about DTO mapping. I will specify in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've settled with a solution involving two constructors, one of them having no default parameters and the other having default parameters and a custom annotation:

```
@RequiresOptIn(
    message = "This constructor uses default values. " +
        "This could be dangerous because it's possible to forget to add new fields in this invocation. " +
        "Only use this if you are sure you don't need any other fields.",
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR)
annotation class DefaultValueConstructor
```

This works mostly fine: As soon as I forget something in Foo.toBar(), the compiler requires me to add an @OptIn annotation. This way, I can call `Bar()` with default parameters whenever I'm sure I don't need any more and also make sure not to forget anything in `Foo.toBar()`.
The only issues with it is that the constructor signatures need to be different. I would need to artificially change the signature of one of the constructors to distinguish them, which I ultimately deemed to complex. Should I resort to the factory pattern or is there another way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I now removed the default parameters from the constructor and went with a factory function on the Bar companion object that has default values. I also changed `DefaultValueConstructor`s `@Target` annotation to include methods and added it to the factory function. Quite happy with that, I am however curious if there are any other solutions.